# Assigning large numbers to double in C

Tags: c, double

When I try to assign a big number to a `double` variable, I get this warning

> sqrt.c:8:11: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
>   double x=28462391747582051264412870770688;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
        printf("MAX_DBL=%.53f\n",DBL_MAX);
        double x=28462391747582051264412870770688; 
}
```

However MAX_DBL is larger than the number I am trying to assign.

Comment: Try `double x = 2.8462391747582051E+31`

Comment: This may be hardware dependent, but it looks like the largest representable `double` in sequence (counting whole numbers, e.g. `1.0, 2.0, ...` ) is `9,007,199,254,740,991` (or `9.007199e+15` and change), so over twice the significant digits puts `x` out into the ether.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: 28462391747582051264412870770688 is exactly representable in the common `double` format (64-bit binary IEEE-754). And the sequence of consecutive representable integers ends with 9007199254740992, not 9007199254740991. 9007199254740993 is the least positive integer that is not representable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - you missed the point. I'm not saying there are not huge numbers exactly representable (or that `x` isn't) -- I'm saying if you count from `1.0 (by 1.0)` the last sequential number representable and distinct from the one before it is `9,007,199,254,740,991`. E.g. `double v1 = 9007199254740991, v2 = v1 + 1.0; if (v1 == v2) { /* is true */ }` It is the *last whole-number in sequence* that is exactly representable and distinct from the one before it -- not the last exactly representable `double`. (you can start a loop `100` or so before it and check -- I was just curious)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The test you show does not test whether `v1` is distinguishable from the one before it. It tests whether `v1` is distinguishable from the one after it. In the `double` format, 9007199254740992 is distinguishable from the integer before it, 9007199254740991, and it is the last such.

Comment: OK, you get my drift, the `...991 != ...992` is the last sequential comparison you can make. So yes, you are correct, I had `last` as `...991` and the comparison failed with the next `...992 != `...993`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double x=28462391747582051264412870770688;
```

The type of the number literal is not `double`, but `int`. This number is too large for an `int`.

If you use a `double` literal:

```
double x=28462391747582051264412870770688.0;
```

The warning disappears, but the number will be rounded to the next representable `double`, if needed. (This particular number here is representable, [as @chux noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148130/assigning-large-numbers-to-double-in-c#comment81248263_47148207).)

Comment: "but the number will be rounded to the next representable double" --> `28462391747582051264412870770688.0` is exactly presentable as a common `double`.  Rounding does not need to occur - in this case.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed. Thanks @chux!